# Issue with URL encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a query string that will return data successfully if I run it in Postman but if I pull the data via Python3 (http.client.HTTPSConnection), the target returns 'bad request'.

The problem:

`/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/service/tickets?customFieldConditions=caption="Escalated To" AND value ="Cloud Operations"`

I have tried putting `+AND+` or `%20and%20` or `%20AND%20` instead of `AND` but no success. For example:

`/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/service/tickets?customFieldConditions=caption="Escalated To"%20AND%20value="Cloud Operations"`

^ This works fine in postman but returns `<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>` when via Python3.

Is there anything else wrong with the url encoding here?

Comment: "Cloud Operations" <- there's still a whitespace

Comment: @Sadap it's in brackets. do i need to escape it?

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: I changed it to "Cloud+Operations" and same error.

Comment: Actually, this may have worked when I just added "Escalated+To". One moment while I confirm.

Comment: @Sadap YOU ARE THE BEST! I was working on this for hours. Feel free to submit this as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode **all** whitespaces in you URL. So the URL should be `/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/service/tickets?customFieldConditions=caption="Escalated%20To"%20AND%20value="Cloud%20Operations"`